# call oracle pl/sql from java with parameter and print dbms_output

Tags: java, oracle

Let's say I've got below java code which eventually prints everything from the pl/sql query:

```
try (CallableStatement call = c.prepareCall(
    "declare "
  + "  num integer := 1000;" 
  + "  num myString:= 'test';" 
  + "begin "
  + "  dbms_output.enable();"
  + "  dbms_output.put_line('abc');"
  + "  dbms_output.put_line('hello');"
  + "  dbms_output.put_line(myString);"
  + "  dbms_output.get_lines(?, num);"
  + "  dbms_output.disable();"
  + "end;"
)) {
    call.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");
    call.execute();

    Array array = null;
    try {
        array = call.getArray(1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList((Object[]) array.getArray()));
    }
    finally {
        if (array != null)
            array.free();
    }
}
```

That works fine but what if I wanted to pass a parameter to the pl/sql query? For example 'myString'?

So it would be something like:

```
 "declare "
  + "  num integer := 1000;" 
  + "  num myString:= ?;" 
  + "begin "
  + "  dbms_output.enable();"
  + "  dbms_output.put_line('abc');"
  + "  dbms_output.put_line('hello');"
  + "  dbms_output.put_line(myString);"
  + "  dbms_output.get_lines(?, num);"
  + "  dbms_output.disable();"
  + "end;"
```

How should I pass this parameter? I know that I should use sth like

```
call.setString(2, "test");
```

but in what place/line?

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

1. In this case, your input parameter will have index=1 and `dbms_output` out parameter will have index=2;
2. There is no type `myString`, so looks like you want `varchar2`;
3. You can use `.setString()`;
4. I've fixed your variable names:

```java
            try (CallableStatement call = c.prepareCall(
                "declare "
              + "  num integer := 1000;"
              + "  str varchar2(100):= ?;"
              + "begin "
              + "  dbms_output.enable();"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line('abc');"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line('hello');"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line(str);"
              + "  dbms_output.get_lines(?, num);"
              + "  dbms_output.disable();"
              + "end;"
            )) {
                call.setString(1, "test");
                call.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");
                call.execute();

                Array array = null;
                try {
                    array = call.getArray(2);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.asList((Object[]) array.getArray()));
                }
                finally {
                    if (array != null)
                        array.free();
                }
            }
```

Results:

```
Connected successfully
[abc, hello, test, null]
```

Another variant is to bind variables by name:

```java
            try (CallableStatement call = c.prepareCall(
                "declare "
              + "  num integer := 1000;"
              + "  str varchar2(100):= :in;"
              + "begin "
              + "  dbms_output.enable();"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line('abc');"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line('hello');"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line(str);"
              + "  dbms_output.get_lines(:out, num);"
              + "  dbms_output.disable();"
              + "end;"
            )) {
                call.setString("in", "test");
                call.registerOutParameter("out", Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");
                call.execute();

                Array array = null;
                try {
                    array = call.getArray("out");
                    System.out.println(Arrays.asList((Object[]) array.getArray()));
                }
                finally {
                    if (array != null)
                        array.free();
                }
            }
```

As you can see I used `:in` and `:out` as bind variables and used these names in `.setString`, `registerOutParameter` and `getArray`.